Build failure on Msys2/ming64 environment by clang with clang64/bin PATH
On Msys2/ming64 environment, tried to build stockfish by use of clang/llvm, as PATH:
clang64/bin precedes over mingw64/bin
use flags:
CXXFLAGS:  -Wall -Wcast-qual -fno-exceptions -std=c++17  -pedantic -Wextra -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes -Wconditional-uninitialized -m64 -DUSE_PTHREADS -DNDEBUG -O3 -funroll-loops -DIS_64BIT -msse -msse3 -mpopcnt -DUSE_POPCNT -DUSE_SSE41 -msse4.1 -DUSE_SSSE3 -mssse3 -DUSE_SSE2 -msse2 -DARCH=x86-64-sse41-popcnt -flto=full -fuse-ld=lld
LDFLAGS:
-fprofile-instr-generate -static -m64 -lpthread  -Wall -Wcast-qual -fno-exceptions -std=c++17  -pedantic -Wextra -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes -Wconditional-uninitialized -m64 -DUSE_PTHREADS -DNDEBUG -O3 -funroll-loops -DIS_64BIT -msse -msse3 -mpopcnt -DUSE_POPCNT -DUSE_SSE41 -msse4.1 -DUSE_SSSE3 -mssse3 -DUSE_SSE2 -msse2 -DARCH=x86-64-sse41-popcnt -flto=full -fuse-ld=lld

link stumbled on:
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>>& std::operator>

but had
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char>>::seekpos

stumble if PATH:
mingw64/bin preceding over clang64/bin
